# Ruby file full path

Tags: ruby, path

I am writing a program where I cycle through all files in sub-folders of a target folder and do stuff with what's writen in it. So my local folder looks like that

```
Folder
--Subfolder
---File
---File
---File
--Subfolder
---File
.
.
.
```

So I have a each loop to cycle through all subfolders and for each subfolder I am calling a method that basically do the same thing but in the subfolder and call for each file another method (parsing it a file argument which I obtained through a `Dir.foreach(folder){ |file| method(file)}` command).

So it looks like this :

```
Dir.foreach(Dir.pwd){ |folder| call_method(folder) }

def call_method(folder) Dir.foreach(folder){|file| reading_method(file) } end
```

That last called method (reading_method) should open called a C method and parse as an argument the full path of the file (so that the C program can open it) so I'm using `File.absolute_path(file)` in the reading_method but instead of returning `C:/folder/subfolder/file` as I want it to, it returns `C:/folder/file` skipping the subfolder (and thus the C program fail to execute).

Is there a way to get the full path of that file ?

Thanks for your help

EDIT : Here is the full code as asked

```
## Module

module GBK_Reader
    PATH         = "Z:/Folder/"
    SAFETY       = true
    SAFETY_COUNT = 10
end


## Methods definitions


def read_file(file)
    path = File.absolute_path(file)
    c_string = `C:/Code/GBK_Reader/bin/Debug/GBK_Reader.exe #{path}`
    return c_string.split(/ /).collect!{|spec| spec.to_i}
end

def read_folder(folder)
    Dir.foreach(folder){ |file|
        next if File.extname(file) != ".gbk"
        temp = read_file(file)
        #$bacteria_specs[0] += temp[0]
        #$bacteria_specs[1] += temp[1]
    }
    return $bacteria_specs
end


## Main

# Look for folder
Dir.chdir(GBK_Reader::PATH)
puts "Directory found"


# Cycle through all sub-folders
$high_gc = {} #Hash to store high GC content bacterias
$count = 0
puts "Array variable set"


Dir.foreach(Dir.pwd){ |file|
    next if file == "." || file == ".."
    break if $count >= GBK_Reader::SAFETY_COUNT
    $count += 1 if GBK_Reader::SAFETY
    $bacteria_specs = [0.00, 0.00, 0.00]
    $path = File.expand_path(file)
    if File.directory?(file)
        # Cycle through all .gbk files in sub-folder and call C program
        read_folder(file)       
    else
        # Call C program to directly evaluate GC content
        c_string = read_file(file) if File.extname(file) == ".gbk"
        $bacteria_specs[0] = c_string[0].to_i
        $bacteria_specs[1] = c_string[1].to_i       
    end
    # Evaluate GC content and store suitable entries
    $bacteria_specs[2] = ($bacteria_specs[0]/$bacteria_specs[1])*100.00
    $high_gc[file] = $bacteria_specs if $bacteria_specs[2] > 60
}

# Display suitable entries
puts "\n\n\n"
puts $high_gc
gets.chomp
```

Comment: Probably not the cause of your problem, but I think you can replace both `Dir.foreach` calls with a single call to `Dir.glob('*/*')`

Comment: Can you show the full code? Your sample code works correctly on my machine.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I don't want to use Dir.glob as I need to read my files folder by folder (and do things according to the "overall results" of the files in one folder and Dir.glob seems to return a list of all files matching the pattern. \nI edited my opening post to show the full code.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I may have found something but it seems ugly so if anyone has a better solution by all means go ahead.

I edited my read_folder method to parse the full path to the read_file method as follow :

```
def read_folder(folder)
    Dir.foreach(folder){ |file|
        next if File.extname(file) != ".gbk"
        path = File.absolute_path(folder)+'/'+File.basename(file)
        temp = read_file(path)
        $bacteria_specs[0] += temp[0]
        $bacteria_specs[1] += temp[1]
    }
    return $bacteria_specs
end
```

And I do get the path I expect. (though my calling the C program still fails so I'll have to check somewhere else :D)